# Can you add S2D to existing vnet on azure. (without using template)

Tags: windows, azure

Can you add S2D to existing vnet on azure. (without using template)

Comment: Would you mind defining S2D? You haven't tagged anything related, so it's unclear. Also: if this is an infrastructure question, and not a programming question, it belongs on ServerFault, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: oh yea, my bad. I m in wrong place. btw S2D stands for Storage Space Direct.